# Can one use ggMarginal on a plot combining points and density lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to add Marginal graphs to my current plot, which displays some data with density lines and some data with points. However, ggMarginal seems to only pick up the data belonging to the first layer or the first subset which is called within geom_point. As anyone an idea how to still achieve my goal using ggMarignal?

I do have come across workarounds with cowplot however in my case it would require a lot of additional work as I produce loads of figures with varying size (which would need all specific adjustment for perfect alignments)

Thanks for any ideas!

Code to reproduce current Output:

```
data=iris
PC_Data=prcomp(data[,1:4])
data2Plot=as.data.frame(cbind(PC_Data$x,Species=data$Species))
data2Plot$Species=as.factor(data2Plot$Species)
p<-ggplot(data2Plot,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,color=Species,fill=Species))+
  stat_density2d(data=subset(data2Plot, Species != "3"),geom="polygon",size=0.2,alpha=0.1) +
  geom_point(data=subset(data2Plot, Species == "3"),size=1)+theme(legend.position = "none")
ggMarginal(p,type="density",groupColour = T,groupFill = T)
```

Current Output

[image: Output:]

Wanted Output:
[image: Wanted Output:]